# Installing Binaries

Tags: linux, yum

I am new to Linux and think I'm missing something. For some reason, the VPS I was given is running Fedora Core 6. From reading around, it looks like yum is pretty handy, so I thought I'd start there. However, when I run the RPM, I get:

```
python-elementtree is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
python-sqlite is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
rpm-python is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
urlgrabber is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
yum-metadata-parser is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
```

okay, so I need these first, no problem - but wait, I go to install yum-metadata-parser - I get another list of dependencies.

On the server, in the usr/bin directory, I see tons of binary files, including yum. Can someone explain how I can install the files from the binaries, or why the binaries are here if the program isn't installed?

Comment: This is just using `yum install foo` ?

Comment: I got this from rpm -Uvh yum-3.0-6-1.fc6.noarch.rpm

Comment: Please provide the output from '/usr/bin/yum check-update'.

Comment: Why did you accept a VM running an obsolete OS?  Talk to whoever you bought the VM from about getting it fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPM system creates a database of sorts to track dependencies. YUM interacts with that RPM database and extends it. It could be that either the base database or the yum extension is corrupted.

If you are brand new to Linux, it might be a better use of your time to reinstall the latest Fedora version and then configure an appropriate set of yum repositories for installing more software. With luck, the person that gave you the VPS could help you. Trying to repair a package management system gets very annoying very quickly.

Personally, I find the Debian/Ubuntu packaging system easier to use, but I disagree with fahadsadah that .deb with apt is inherently better than .rpm with yum. I would suggest using what others around you are using, as you will have a ready source of advice if you run into trouble.

Comment: FWIW, the Debian and Ubuntu support communities (IRC/forums) are some of the biggest around.

Comment: +1 for both informative response and refusing to perpetuate the deb/rpm & apt/yum flamewars

Answer (score 0):

yum **is** installed if it's in /usr/bin (it's usually installed by default, anyway)

If there's a package you want to install, use `yum install packagename`.

Comment: YUM doesn't work, when I go to use it, it says python dependencies are missing, when I get those dependencies and go to install them, there are more dependencies. Is there an easy way to install everything I need, or should I clear my weekend to track down everything I need to run one program?

Comment: If you don't like managing dependencies manually, try Debian or Ubuntu rather than Fedora. They both use apt, which is superior to yum. All dependencies are handled automatically and smartly, and conflicts resolved with minimal damage.

Comment: yum is pretty well equivalent to apt in my experience.  yum does all the dependency handling you describe.

Comment: I've had plenty of problems with yum in the past. Have these been resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

If yum isn't working on yet you'll need to download the RPMs that it is missing and then install them manually using 'rpm --install '

Finding the RPMs can be tough, but head to Fedora's site, browse through the downloads until you hit the correct directory for the version you have and start downloading.

If you just have a terminal log-in on your machine you'll want to be using wget to download - wget  which will fetch the file for you. (curl would also work, but is less often installed).

TBH, as has been said above, you might want to talk to your provider about setting up a more complete system for a beginner - better yet, install linux, or use a liveCD on your desktop/laptop at home. Far easier to play on than a remote machine.